# sql select columns based on name type

Tags: sql-server

I am working in Microsoft SQL and I have a table where the column names are like `'INT001', 'INT002'` all the way to `'INT300'` but the columns don't show up in the particular order as the names above.

I want to select only columns from `'INT001' to 'INT096'` i.e. 97 columns from 300 columns and the columns occur in random order in the table.

I don't even have a clue where to begin.

Edit: I don't want to type the 97 column names when they already have a pattern I can use if possible.

Comment: What's wrong on going for `select INT001, INT002, INT003,...INT096 from Table`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in a query... What you can do is dynamically generate the query;

You can generate this in a number of ways... something like so (using just numbers to build the column names);

```
DECLARE @QueryString as varchar(max);

SELECT @QueryString = 'SELECT ';

SELECT 
    @QueryString = COALESCE(@QueryString + '[INT' + TheNumber + '],', '')
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT('000'+CAST(number AS VARCHAR(3)),3) AS TheNumber FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 96) numbers

SELECT @QueryString = left(@QueryString, len(@QueryString) - 1) + ' FROM [YourTableName]'

print @QueryString
```

Gives us

```
SELECT [INT000],[INT001],[INT002],[INT003],[INT004],[INT005],[INT006],[INT007],[INT008],[INT009],[INT010],[INT011],[INT012],[INT013],[INT014],[INT015],[INT016],[INT017],[INT018],[INT019],[INT020],[INT021],[INT022],[INT023],[INT024],[INT025],[INT026],[INT027],[INT028],[INT029],[INT030],[INT031],[INT032],[INT033],[INT034],[INT035],[INT036],[INT037],[INT038],[INT039],[INT040],[INT041],[INT042],[INT043],[INT044],[INT045],[INT046],[INT047],[INT048],[INT049],[INT050],[INT051],[INT052],[INT053],[INT054],[INT055],[INT056],[INT057],[INT058],[INT059],[INT060],[INT061],[INT062],[INT063],[INT064],[INT065],[INT066],[INT067],[INT068],[INT069],[INT070],[INT071],[INT072],[INT073],[INT074],[INT075],[INT076],[INT077],[INT078],[INT079],[INT080],[INT081],[INT082],[INT083],[INT084],[INT085],[INT086],[INT087],[INT088],[INT089],[INT090],[INT091],[INT092],[INT093],[INT094],[INT095],[INT096] FROM [YourTableName]
```

This would also be easier and better using sys.columns to list the column names but since I don't have your table here or time to mock it up I have gone with a simple numbers one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your query by dynamically creating the SQL.

```
DECLARE @MAX INT = 97;
DECLARE @NUM INT = 1;
DECLARE @COLUMN NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (1000) = 'SELECT ';

WHILE @NUM <= @MAX
BEGIN
    SET @COLUMN = RIGHT(REPLICATE(0, 3) + CAST(@NUM AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)
    SET @NUM = @NUM + 1;
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '[INT' + @COLUMN + '], '
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'FROM [TABLENAME]'

SELECT @SQL --This is just to see the query
```

Once you have the query you can execute it by copy and paste or you can use this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```